# Silverstripe Filter by parent page properties

Tags: silverstripe

When querying the database via dataobject orm, how can records be filtered by the properties of the page's parent?

So what I have in mind is something like:

```
$facilities_by_keyword = Facility::get()->filter('Parent.tags:partialmatch', $tag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the all parent pages first. Then get the Facility pages that are children of any of those parent pages:

```php
$parentPages = Page::get()->filter('Parent.tags:partialmatch', $tag);
$parentIDs = $parentPages->getIDList();
$facilities_by_keyword = Facility::get()->where('ParentID IN (' . implode(',', $parentIDs) . ')');
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I guess the only concern would be performance implications of doing 2 database queries.  nice and readable though, ill think ill go with it.